# How to cancel the indentation of first line in paragraphs?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I just want to cancel the first line indentation in every section paragraph (include the Abstract). Thank you for any kind help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \vskip5em
    \begin{center}\LARGE#1\end{center}
    \vskip5em}%
}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}

\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\small\quotation
  {\bfseries\noindent{\large\abstractname}\par\nobreak\smallskip}}
  {\endquotation}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Here goes the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\setlength{\parskip} {0.8em}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section\\}
This document is for testing.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Short tip: select text and click the button marked `{}` above the textfield to highlight it as code.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm sorry to forget edit it first. Thank you for your tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this line into your preamble in order to set `\parindent` (the indent length) to zero:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

If you want to prevent indentation in a given paragraph, put `\noindent` at the beginning of this paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Having no indentation and no increased lineskip between paragraphs makes it difficult to see where a paragraph ends. To "reverse" LaTeX' standard behaviour, you can use `\usepackage{parskip}`.

Comment: however, `parskip.sty` is also a post-hoc solution; you really want a class with this arrangement built-in.  `artikel3` from the `ntgclass` bundle can do it; `koma-script` or `memoir` _might_ help, but their aim is typographic excellence, rather than word-processor hacks like this.

Comment: Very true. KOMA-Script takes a bit of configuring until it's back to the "default look", so it may or may not work as a drop-in replacement.